# Is it possible to dynamically load a .NET 6.0 dll into a .NET Framework 4.5 project?

Tags: .net, dll, .net-6.0, .net-framework-version

Is it possible to dynamically load a .NET 6.0 dll into a .NET Framework 4.5 project?
I know that you cannot do it as a normal reference but maybe there is some kind of dynamically form of loading it.

Answer (score 2):

No (unless you consider starting the .NET 6.0 executable/dll as a separate process, though it is not loading the dll). .NET (Core) is a complete rewrite of the runtime so it isn't compatible with the CLR in .NET Framework. You will have to migrate your project to the newer runtime (which can include changing the project structure, managing incompatible dependencies). Check out the [Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/porting/) on the subject.

Another option is "porting" the .NET 6 dll to [.NET Standard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard?tabs=net-standard-1-2) (I think 1.2 version is supported by .NET Framework 4.5.1). But either way .NET Framework 4.5 is out of support AFAIK, so you better upgrade as soon as possible.